# Does bounded operator maps a bounded sequence to bounded sequence?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory

If we have a Bounded linear operator $T:X\to Y$ , then can we say if I take a bounded sequence ${f_n}$ in $X-$norm then $T(f_n)$ is also bounded in $Y-norm.$

I am saying this above because since we have $T$ as a bounded linear operator so this means $\lVert T\rVert_Y \leq C. \lVert f \rVert_{X}$ for some $C>0.$ Ans since we also have $\lVert f \rVert_{X} \leq D$ which implies $\lVert T \rVert_{Y} \leq C.D$ which means $T$ is bounded in $Y-$ norm.

Comment: The condition is equivalent to the boundedness of $T.

Comment: You mean if $T$ is a bounded operator then we can say that for a bounded sequence $f_n$ in $X-$norm, $Tf_n$ will be bounded in $Y-$ norm and vice versa.

Comment: Yes, especially "vice versa" as one direction is given in the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\def\norm#1#2{{|\!|#1|\!|}_{#2}}$

The fact that $T$ is bounded means for some $C>0$, $\norm{T(p)}{Y}\le C\norm{p}{X}$ for any $p\in X$.

Given a bounded sequence $a_1,a_2,\ldots$ in $X$, there exists $M>0$ for which $\norm{a_n}{X}<M$ for all $n\ge 1$. Then $\norm{T(a_n)}{Y}\le C\norm{a_n}{X}$ for all $n$. I will let you take it from here.

Comment: so after $||T(a_n)||_{y} \leq C||a_n||_{X}$ we can say that $||T(a_n)||_{Y} \leq C.M$ since we have $||a_n||_{X}<M$, that means $T$ is bounded in $Y-$norm. Am I right.

Comment: Yes the new bound is just $CM$. By the way, you can write the multiplication dot with `\cdot` (or just omit it and write $CM$ when appropriate).

Comment: Thank you so much!